# onclicklistener for listview row with multiple items

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, listviewitem

I have a custom adpater for an expandable listview. Each child of the expandable listview has multiple items, and I want to set a click listener for each item.

When I set the clicklistener, it always take two clicks to get the item to perform the task. The first click selects the entire row, then the second click does what it need to do. How do I prevent this? Here is the code:

> myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        long id) {

                    final int grp = groupPosition;
                    final int chdp = childPosition;


                    TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewWithTag("title");
                    txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            child = myFolderlist.getArray().get(grp)
                                    .get(chdp);
                            goToItem(child, none, all, false);

                        }
                    });
```

I have tried setting the clicklistener in the adapter, but the code I want to run is not accessible from the adapter. I also set the onclick in the layout, but this prevents me from getting the groupPosition and childPosition as is ignores the clicklistener altogether.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you will have to set the listeners in the adapter and make your code accessible, with something like a messagebus of some sort. you wont be able to access the views from your activiy/fragment. if you did your code would be ugly at best, if possible, not sure

Comment: I tried making the code public and static, however I couldn't because i'm creating a dialog in goToItem

Answer (score 0):

As you set the OnClickListener for the TextView in ListView's onClick Method, the first click will set the TextView - OnClickListener, and the second click invokes that listener.

A possible solution is calling `txt.performClick` after setting TextView's OnClickListener

Comment: sound like a good idea. There are actually three textviews in the row so i'd need to figure out which one got the click. Let me try that.

Comment: all the info i seem to get is that the entire row got a click because the first click automatically goes to the entire layout.

Comment: Instead of using a textview, I decided to try a checkbox (and I can customize it to look like a text view), and set the onclick for the checkbox in the layout to run my code; then I used the setOnCheckedChangeListener in my adapter to send the data about its position in the listview. This works because both onclick and oncheckchange run seperately.

Comment: ok. changed it back to using a textview and using ontouch to update location. works perfeectly now

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want the click to be done when the TextView is clicked?

```
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                    View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    long id) {

                final int grp = groupPosition;
                final int chdp = childPosition;


                TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewWithTag("title");
                txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        child = myFolderlist.getArray().get(grp)
                                .get(chdp);
                        goToItem(child, none, all, false);

                    }
                });
                txt.performClick();
             }
```

else when the whole child should initialize work:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                long id) {

            final int grp = groupPosition;
            final int chdp = childPosition;

            child = myFolderlist.getArray().get(grp)
                            .get(chdp);
            goToItem(child, none, all, false);

         }
```